# Проблема со swipe у ViewPager при обновленных Сервисах Google Play

Tags: android-viewpager, android, swipe, google-maps-api-2

**Добрый день!**  
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: имеется `ViewPager` с тремя элементами. У среднего элемента вот такая структура

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            />
  <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

При этом если свайпать от края экрана, то все перелистывается хорошо, иначе, если это делать по середине элемента, то ничего не происходит. У боковых элементов без карты все работает хорошо.

Выяснил, что это происходит с обновленными Сервисами Google Play **от 6 августа**, ставил предыдущую версию (**v 3.1.59**) все прекрасно работает. 
Есть идеи, как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим образом

```
uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```